# OpenCV and MATLAB speed comparison

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, opencv

I've started to use OpenCV with Visual C++ 2010 Express, because it was supposed to be faster than MATLAB.

In order to do a fair comparison between both, I'm running a program where I convert a RGB image to its gray scale correspondent and I calculate the conversion image space operation elapsed time.

Using `cvtColor` command to do the task in C++ Release, it takes me around 5 ms, average. Doing the same operation in MATLAB, takes me more or less the same average time (the codes are bellow).

I already tested, and both programs are working fine.

Does anybody have any idea if I can improve the OpenCV speed?

**C++ code.**

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
    cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";

    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}

double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart-CounterStart)/PCFreq;
}

int main()
{
    double time;
    Mat im, result;
    im = imread("C:/Imagens_CV/circles_rgb.jpg");
    StartCounter();
    cvtColor(im,result, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    time = GetCounter();
    cout <<"Process time: "<< time << endl;
}
```

**MATLAB code**

```
tic
img_gray = rgb2gray(img_rgb);
toc
```

Comment: FYI: in terms of timing, it's better to compute the average time over a number of times.

Comment: Yes, I have done this. 5 ms is the average time. I added this information in the question.

Comment: Why should matlab be slower in this case? If it provides a function, it likely has an optimized implementation of it. What is slow is programming in matlab, doing explicit loops, etc.

Comment: The matlab code you are using, eventually uses a Mex file (ore something like that), in such case the speed would be more or less the same. You can also compare with OpenCV in Python ;)

Comment: you'll be happy to know that MathWorks is making it easier to call OpenCV from MATLAB if you wish (by writing MEX-functions): http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/opencv-interface.html (this is new in R2014b CSVT-toolbox). There is also the excellent [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color conversion in OpenCV will make *extensive use of [Intel IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp)* if it is available at compile time.  See [modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L5524).  [More info from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-open-source-computer-vision-library-opencv-faq).  Note that this code has no OpenMP pragmas or TBB code, so that won't help here.

The exciting bit is that Intel has granted OpenCV the right to use a subset of IPP for free, incuding these functions.  See the third item in the [release summary](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0-alpha.html) for more info.  But you need to use at least OpenCV 3.0 to get this free functionality; otherwise you need to compile with your own copy of IPP.

[image]

Clearly, `cvtColor` (far left) does not benefit much, but it gets a little boost.  Other functions do much better.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the call to [`rgb2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) function in MATLAB (`edit rgb2gray.m`), you'll find that it eventually calls a private MEX-function `imapplymatrixc.mexw64` implemented in C++.

In fact if you load this shared library into a tool like "Dependency Walker", you'll see it has a dependency on `tbb.dll` which indicates the function is multi-threaded using [Intel TBB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threading_Building_Blocks) library.

While it doesn't seem to be the case for color conversion functions, the Image Processing Toolbox does use [Intel IPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Performance_Primitives) library for some of its [image arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-arithmetic-sect1.html) functions (there is a [setting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/iptprefs.html) you can control to enable/disable the use of "hardware optimization" `ippl`: `iptsetpref('UseIPPL', true)`).

In addition, there is a version of the function that runs on the GPU (CUDA) when using `gpuArray` input arrays (`edit gpuArray>rgb2gray.m`). This requires the Parallel Computing Toolbox.

So it is safe to say the function is well optimized!